# C++ substring matching implementation

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, substring, string-matching

I have two strings, "hello" an "eo" for instance, and I wish to find duplicate characaters between the two strings, that is: 'e' and 'o' in this example.

My algorithm would go this way

```
 void find_duplicate(char* str_1, char* str_2, int len1, int len2)
 {
     char c ;

     if(len1 < len2)
     {
        int* idx_1 = new int[len1]; // record elements in little string
        // that are matched in big string
        for(int k = 0 ; k < len1 ; k++)
              idx_1[k] = 0;

        int* idx_2 = new int[len2]; // record if element in str_2 has been 
        // matched already or not
        for(int k = 0 ; k < len2 ; k++)
              idx_2[k] = 0;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < len2 ; i++)
        {     
            c = str_1[i];

            for(int j = 0 ; j < len1 ; j++)
            {
                 if(str_2[j] == c)
                 {
                    if(idx_2[j] == 0) // this element in str_2 has not been matched yet
                    {
                         idx_1[i] = j + 1; // mark ith element in idx as matched in string 2 at pos j
                         idx_2[j] = 1;
                    }
                 }
             }
         }

         // now idx_1 and idx_2 contain matches info, let's remove matches.
         char* str_1_new = new char[len1];
         char* str_2_new = new char[len2];
         int kn = 0;
         for(int k = 0 ; k < len1 ; k++)
         {
            if(idx_1[k] > 0)
            {
                 str_1_new[kn] = str_1[k];
                 kn++;
            }
         }

         kn = 0;
         for(int k = 0 ; k < len2 ; k++)
         {
             if(idx_2[k] > 0)
             {
                 str_2_new[kn] = str_2[k];
                 kn++;
             }
         }
      }
      else
      {
            // same here, switching roles (do it yourself)
       }
  }
```

i feel my solution is awkward:
- symetry of both cases in first if/else and code duplication
- time complexity: 2*len1*len2 operations for finding duplicates, then len1 + len2 operations for removal
- space complexity: two len1 and two len2 char*.

What if `len1` and `len2` are not given (with and without resort to STL vector) ?

could you provide your implementation of this algo ?

thanks

Comment: I would sort the characters in the strings and the compare them in one sweep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it isn't substring matching problem - it is problem of finding common characters between two strings.

Your solution works in **O(n*m)**, where *n=len1* and *m=len2* in your code. You could easily solve the same problem in **O(n+m+c)** time by counting characters in each of strings (where c is equal to size of character set). This algorithm is called [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Sample code implementing this in your case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> // for strlen and memset

const int CHARLEN = 256; //number of possible chars

using namespace std;

// returns table of char duplicates
char* find_duplicates(const char* str_1, const char* str_2, const int len1, const int len2)
{
  int *count_1 = new int[CHARLEN];
  int *count_2 = new int[CHARLEN];
  char *duplicates = new char[CHARLEN+1]; // we hold duplicate chars here
  int dupl_len = 0; // length of duplicates table, we insert '\0' at the end
  memset(count_1,0,sizeof(int)*CHARLEN);
  memset(count_2,0,sizeof(int)*CHARLEN);
  for (int i=0; i<len1; ++i)
  {
    ++count_1[str_1[i]];
  }
  for (int i=0; i<len2; ++i)
  {
    ++count_2[str_2[i]];
  }

  for (int i=0; i<CHARLEN; ++i)
  {
    if (count_1[i] > 0 && count_2[i] > 0)
    {
      duplicates[dupl_len] = i;
      ++dupl_len;
    }
  }
  duplicates[dupl_len]='\0';
  delete count_1;
  delete count_2;
  return duplicates;
}

int main()
{
  const char* str_1 = "foobar";
  const char* str_2 = "xro";
  char* dup =   find_duplicates(str_1, str_2, strlen(str_1), strlen(str_2));
  cout << "str_1: \"" << str_1 << "\" str_2: \"" << str_2 << "\"\n";
  cout << "duplicates: \"" << dup << "\"\n";
  delete dup;
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that I am also sorting the output here. If you do not want to do that, you can skip the counting of characters in second string and just start comparing duplicates on the go.

If you, however, intend to be able to detect multiple duplicates of the same letter (e.g. if "banana" and "arena" should output "aan" instead of "an"), then you can just substract the number of counts in current solution and adjust the output accordingly.

Comment: `O(n+m+c)`, where c is the size of the charset

Comment: @Zaroth Note that `new int[CHARLEN]();` would initialize your array with 0 elements. Also you could simplify a lot your code using `std::vector` (that are 0-initialized and don't need to be explicitly deleted)

Comment: @log0 the `()` trick is a bit voodooish; since this is an educational answer, I tried to make my code as readable as possible. Also, please note that OP requested a solution without using `std::vector`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath/Zaroth I think you can just use one count vector and simply add the character any time you notice the count is different to 0. In this case the complexity is indeed O(len1+len2) with memory footprint ~256

Comment: @Zaroth I don't think the OP is opposed to the used of `st::vector` he was wondering if it was changing the complexity.

Comment: @log0: ?? in that case c=256 (note: you can use hashing, vector will give you the same results as an array)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath no I mean you don't actually need to scan the count vector at the end.

Comment: @log0: you still have to initialize it (O wise same as scanning). also, as Zaroth mentioned, you might just want to print "an"

Comment: @KarolyHorvath See my answer below

Comment: @log0: yes... and.. ? my reasoning still holds. I see an O(n*m) and an O(n+m+c) solution there.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<char> duplicates;
for (auto c1: std::string(str_1))
  for (auto c2: std::string(str_2))
    if (c1 == c2)
      duplicates.push_back(c1);
```

or if you don't have a c++11 compliant compiler.

```
std::vector<char> duplicates;
std::string s1(str_1);
std::string s2(str_2);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++)
  for (std::size_t j = 0; j < s2.size(); j++)
    if (s1[i] == s2[j])
      duplicates.push_back(s1[i]);
```

-- based on Zaroth answer

```
std::vector<int> count(256,0);
for (auto c : std::string(str_1))
 count[c] += 1;
for (auto c : std::string(str_2))
 if (count[c] > 0)
   duplicates.push_back(c);
```

Comment: `for (auto c1: std::string(str_1))`, this is C++11, right? what if iam with C++ for vs2010

Comment: does this mean that at runtime std::size_t is "known to be" size of a character in string?

Comment: @fonjibe vs2010 support the auto keyword http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx

Comment: You have i++ instead of j++ in the inner loop.

Comment: @log0 i have a doubt it is deprecated auto specifier, as mentionned here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration, that is allowed in vs2010. btw, what is this syntax:`for (auto c1: std::string(str_1))`, what does this mean? i thought for argument to be ternary

Comment: @finjibe the return type of the `size()` method of STL container is `sts::size_t`, this type guaranty that it is big enough to represent any size that can fit in your memory.

Comment: no, in fact the old `C` meaning of auto is deprecated. Nobody was really using it anyway. Its new sense, means "let the compiler infer the type for me" and is a brand new C++11 feature.

Comment: @fonjibe `for (auto c1: std::string(str_1))` means: for every element `c1` in a temporary `std::string` constructed with `str_1`.

Comment: antitrust is an interesting name for someone using a microsoft compiler.